# How to save images in Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, image, upload

I have a function in my controller that works when I upload images. They are being saved successfully, but the thing is, they are being saved with 0 octets. When I try to access them, I get this "error while charging the image."

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $imageData = $request->input('imgBase64');
    $imageData = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $imageData);
    $imageData = str_replace(' ', '+', $imageData);
    $imageData = base64_decode($imageData);

    $imageName = time() . '.png';
    $path = public_path() . '/photos/' . $imageName;
    file_put_contents($path, $imageData);
    
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Image saved successfully.',
        'image_name' => $imageName
    ]);
}
```

I tried solutions from github/youtube.

Comment: Avoid base64 encoding it in the front-end; it's inefficient and makes this all more complicated than it has to be. Once you've undone that, see https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#file-uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it has data:image/png prefix! try:

```
$imageData = $request->input('imgBase64');
$imageData = explode(";base64,", $imageData);
$imageData = base64_decode($imageData[1]);

$imageName = time() . '.png';
$path = public_path() . '/photos/' . $imageName;
file_put_contents($path, $imageData);
```